# D3.js Spider/Radar chart multiple scales on axes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to make a graph with different scales on the different axes of my graph, like in the example below.

Is there a function? Or do I have to rebuild ?

[image: scale]

My code here :

```
 axis.append("text")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .style("font-size", "11px")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("x", function (d, i) { return rScale(maxValue * config.labelFactor) * Math.cos(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2); })
      .attr("y", function (d, i) { return rScale(maxValue * config.labelFactor) * Math.sin(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2); })
      .text(function (d) { return d })
      .call(wrap, config.wrapWidth);
```

#### UPDATE:

Found another solution with Apache Echarts: https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=radar. It fully supports most things I need.

Answer (score 1):

I find a solution to my problem so I post it here

I just make a for loop and play with angle the result is not so bad.

If someone has the trick to flip horizontaly the text.

[image]

```
function RadarChart(id, options, carId) {


  d3.csv("cars.csv").then(function (data) {

    //Name,Type,AWD,RWD,Retail_Price,Dealer_Cost,Engine_Size,Cyl,
    //Acura 3.5 RL 4dr,Sedan,0,0,43755,39014,3.5,6
    //Horsepower,CityMilesPerGallon,HighwayMilesPerGallon,Weight,WheelBase,Len,Width
    //225,18,24,3880,115,197,72

    var data = [
      [
        { axis: "Length", value: data[carId]["Len"] },
        { axis: "Width", value: data[carId]["Width"] },
        { axis: "Wheel base", value: data[carId]["WheelBase"] },
        { axis: "Retail price", value: data[carId]["Retail_Price"] },
        { axis: "Engine size", value: data[carId]["Engine_Size"] },
        { axis: "HorsePower", value: data[carId]["Horsepower"] },
      ],];


    var scaleList = [

      [0, 100, 200, 300, 400],//"Length"
      [0, 50, 100, 150, 200],//"Width"
      [0, 50, 100, 150, 200],//"Wheel base":
      [0, 25000, 50000, 75000, 100000],//"Retail price"
      [0, 2, 4, 6, 8],//"Engine size":
      [0, 100, 200, 300, 400],//"HorsePower"


    ];


    var config = {
      // circle
      margin: { top: 40, right: 70, bottom: 40, left: 70 }, //The margins of the SVG
      levels: 3,                //How many levels or inner circles should there be drawn
      labelFactor: 1.25,    //How much farther than the radius of the outer circle should the labels be placed
      wrapWidth: 60,        //The number of pixels after which a label needs to be given a new line
      opacityArea: 0.35,    //The opacity of the area of the blob
      dotRadius: 4,             //The size of the colored circles of each blog
      opacityCircles: 0.1,  //The opacity of the circles of each blob
      strokeWidth: 2,       //The width of the strok a  e around each blob
    };


    var myColor = d3.scaleOrdinal()
      .domain(data)
      .range(d3.schemeSet2);

    //Put all of the options into a variable called cfg
    if ('undefined' !== typeof options) {
      for (var i in options) {
        if ('undefined' !== typeof options[i]) { config[i] = options[i]; }
      }//for i
    }//if


    var radius = (window.innerWidth + window.innerHeight) / 15;

    var allAxis = (data[0].map(function (i, j) { return i.axis })), //Names of each axis
      total = allAxis.length,                   //The number of different axes

      //Format = d3.format('%'),                //Percentage formatting
      Format = d3.format('.1f'),
      angleSlice = Math.PI * 2 / total;     //The width in radians of each "slice"

    //Scale for the radius

    //Remove whatever chart with the same id/class was present before
    d3.select(id).select("svg").remove();

    //Initiate the radar chart SVG
    var svg = d3.select(id).append("svg")
      .attr("width", radius * 2 + config.margin.left + config.margin.right)
      .attr("height", radius * 2 + config.margin.top + config.margin.bottom)
      .attr("class", "radar" + id);
    //Append a g element        
    var g = svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + (radius + config.margin.left) + "," + (radius + config.margin.top) + ")");

    //Filter for the outside glow
    var filter = g.append('defs').append('filter').attr('id', 'glow'),
      feGaussianBlur = filter.append('feGaussianBlur').attr('stdDeviation', '2.5').attr('result', 'coloredBlur'),
      feMerge = filter.append('feMerge'),
      feMergeNode_1 = feMerge.append('feMergeNode').attr('in', 'coloredBlur'),
      feMergeNode_2 = feMerge.append('feMergeNode').attr('in', 'SourceGraphic');

    //Wrapper for the grid & axes
    var axisGrid = g.append("g").attr("class", "axisWrapper");

    //Draw the background circles
    axisGrid.selectAll(".levels")
      .data(d3.range(1, (config.levels + 1)).reverse())
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("class", "gridCircle")
      .attr("r", function (d, i) {


        return radius / config.levels * d;
      })
      .style("fill", "#CDCDCD")
      .style("stroke", "#CDCDCD")
      .style("fill-opacity", config.opacityCircles)
      .style("filter", "url(#glow)");


    var rScaleList = [
      d3.scaleLinear().range([0, radius - 50]).domain([0, (scaleList[0])[4]]),//"Length"
      d3.scaleLinear().range([0, radius - 50]).domain([0, (scaleList[1])[4]]),//"Width"
      d3.scaleLinear().range([0, radius - 50]).domain([0, (scaleList[2])[4]]),//"Wheel base":
      d3.scaleLinear().range([0, radius - 50]).domain([0, (scaleList[3])[4]]),//"Retail price"
      d3.scaleLinear().range([0, radius - 50]).domain([0, (scaleList[4])[4]]),//"Engine size":
      d3.scaleLinear().range([0, radius - 50]).domain([0, (scaleList[5])[4]]),//"HorsePower"
    ];






    //Create the straight lines radiating outward from the center
    var axis = axisGrid.selectAll(".axis")
      .data(allAxis)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis");

    //scale
    for (let echelleNumero = 0; echelleNumero < 6; echelleNumero++) {



      axis.append("text")
        .attr("class", "textscale")
        .style("font-size", "10px")
        .attr("fill", "#737373")
        .data(scaleList[echelleNumero])
        .attr("x", 4) // decale echelle  en abscisse
        .attr("dy", "-8")
        .attr("y", function (d, i) { return (-(radius) * i) / scaleList[echelleNumero].length; }) // gere espacement entre données en y 
        .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
          var angleI = angleSlice * (echelleNumero) * 180 / Math.PI;   // the angle to rotate the label
          var flip = (angleI < 90 || angleI > 270) ? false : true; // 180 if label needs to be flipped
          if (flip == true) {

            return "rotate(" + (angleI) + ")";

          } else {

            return "rotate(" + (angleI) + ")";


          }

        })
        .text(function (d) {
          if (echelleNumero == 0) {
            return Format(d);
          } else {
            if (d != 0) {
              return Format(d);
            } else { return; }
          }

        });
    }



    //Append the lines
    axis.append("line")
      .attr("x1", 0)
      .attr("y1", 0)
      .attr("x2", function (d, i) { return radius * Math.cos(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2); })
      .attr("y2", function (d, i) { return radius * Math.sin(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2); })
      .attr("class", "line")
      .style("stroke", "white")
      .style("stroke-width", "2px");



    //Append the labels at each axis
    axis.append("text")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .style("font-size", "11px")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      //.attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("x", function (d, i) { return (radius * 1.3) * Math.cos(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2); })
      .attr("y", function (d, i) { return (radius * 1.1) * Math.sin(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2); })
      .text(function (d) { return d });



    var blobWrapper = g.selectAll(".radarWrapper")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "radarWrapper");


    //The radial line function
    var radarLine = d3.lineRadial()
      .curve(d3.curveCardinalClosed)
      .radius(function (d, i) { return rScaleList[i](d.value); })
      .angle(function (d, i) { return i * angleSlice; });



    //Append the backgrounds    
    blobWrapper
      .append("path")
      .attr("class", "radarArea")
      .attr("d", function (d, i) { return radarLine(d); })

      .style("fill", function (d, i) { return myColor(i) })
      .style("fill-opacity", config.opacityArea)
      .on('mouseover', function (d, i) {
        //Dim all blobs
        d3.selectAll(".radarArea")
          .transition().duration(200)
          .style("fill-opacity", 0.1);
        //Bring back the hovered over blob
        d3.select(this)
          .transition().duration(200)
          .style("fill-opacity", 0.7);
      })
      .on('mouseout', function () {
        //Bring back all blobs
        d3.selectAll(".radarArea")
          .transition().duration(200)
          .style("fill-opacity", config.opacityArea);
      });

    //Create the outlines   
    blobWrapper.append("path")
      .attr("class", "radarStroke")
      .attr("d", function (d, i) { return radarLine(d); })
      .style("stroke-width", config.strokeWidth + "px")
      .style("stroke", function (d, i) { return myColor(i) })
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("filter", "url(#glow)");

    //Append the dot
    blobWrapper.selectAll(".radarCircle")
      .data(function (d, i) { return d; })
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "radarCircle")
      .attr("r", config.dotRadius)
      .attr("cx", function (d, i) { return rScaleList[i](d.value) * Math.cos(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2); })
      .attr("cy", function (d, i) { return rScaleList[i](d.value) * Math.sin(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2); })
      .style("fill", myColor(0))
      .style("fill-opacity", 0.8);

    //Wrapper for the invisible circles on top
    var blobCircleWrapper = g.selectAll(".radarCircleWrapper")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "radarCircleWrapper");

    //Append a set of invisible circles on top for the mouseover pop-up
    blobCircleWrapper.selectAll(".radarInvisibleCircle")
      .data(function (d, i) { return d; })
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "radarInvisibleCircle")
      .attr("r", config.dotRadius * 1.5)
      .attr("cx", function (d, i) { return rScaleList[i](d.value) * Math.cos(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2); })
      .attr("cy", function (d, i) { return rScaleList[i](d.value) * Math.sin(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2); })
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("pointer-events", "all")
      .on("mouseover", function (d, i) {
        newX = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('cx')) - 10;
        newY = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('cy')) - 10;

        tooltip
          .attr('x', newX)
          .attr('y', newY)
          .text(Format(d.value))
          .transition().duration(200)
          .style('opacity', 1);
      })
      .on("mouseout", function () {
        tooltip.transition().duration(200)
          .style("opacity", 0);
      });

    //Set up the small tooltip for when you hover over a circle
    var tooltip = g.append("text")
      .attr("class", "tooltip")
      .style("opacity", 0);

    //Taken from http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321
    //Wraps SVG text    
    function wrap(text, width) {
      text.each(function () {
        var text = d3.select(this),
          words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
          word,
          line = [],
          lineNumber = 0,
          lineHeight = 1.4, // ems
          y = text.attr("y"),
          x = text.attr("x"),
          dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
          tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", x).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");

        while (word = words.pop()) {
          line.push(word);
          tspan.text(line.join(" "));
          if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
            line.pop();
            tspan.text(line.join(" "));
            line = [word];
            tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", x).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
          }
        }
      });
    }//wrap 



  });





}//RadarChart
```